# Problem with check win tic-tac-toe in javascript

Tags: javascript

I everyone. I need your help with my project. I make a tic tac toe game with javascript. Everything goes well until I had to implement a check win function. I think it's logically correct but it doesn't work. I'll post the entire code below, hoping someone can explain why the function doesn't work. HTML :

```js
const turno = document.getElementById("turno");
    const playerX = "X";
    const playerO = "O";
    const str = "Player who won : ";
    let nextPlayer = "";
    let cella1 = document.getElementById("cella1");
    let cella2 = document.getElementById("cella2");
    let cella3 = document.getElementById("cella3");
    let cella4 = document.getElementById("cella4");
    let cella5 = document.getElementById("cella5");
    let cella6 = document.getElementById("cella6");
    let cella7 = document.getElementById("cella7");
    let cella8 = document.getElementById("cella8");
    let cella9 = document.getElementById("cella9");
    
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        turno.innerText = playerX;
        nextPlayer = playerO;
    });
    
    cella1.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella1.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella1.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella1.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
    
        win();
    })
    cella2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella2.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella2.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella2.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
    })
    cella3.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella3.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella3.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella3.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX; 
            nextPlayer = playerO;   
        }
        win();
    })
    cella4.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella4.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella4.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella4.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    cella5.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella5.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella5.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella5.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    cella6.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella6.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella6.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella6.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    cella7.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella7.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella7.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella7.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    cella8.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella8.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella8.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cella8.innerText);
        
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    cella9.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cella9.innerText = turno.innerText;
        cella9.style.pointerEvents = "none"
        console.log(cella9.innerText);
        
        if (turno.innerText === playerX) {
            turno.innerText = playerO;
            nextPlayer = playerX;
        }
        else {
            turno.innerText = playerX;
            nextPlayer = playerO;
        }
        win();
        
    })
    
    function win() {
        if( cella1.innerText === cella2.innerText && cella2.innerText === cella3.innerText ||
            cella4.innerText === cella5.innerText && cella5.innerText === cella6.innerText ||
            cella7.innerText === cella8.innerText && cella8.innerText === cella9.innerText ||
            cella1.innerText === cella4.innerText && cella4.innerText === cella7.innerText ||
            cella2.innerText === cella5.innerText && cella5.innerText === cella8.innerText ||
            cella3.innerText === cella6.innerText && cella6.innerText === cella9.innerText ||
            cella1.innerText === cella5.innerText && cella5.innerText === cella9.innerText ||
            cella3.innerText === cella5.innerText && cella5.innerText === cella7.innerText) {
                console.log("true");
            }
            else {
                console.log("false");
            }
    }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap');
    
    html, body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 700px;
        height: 900px;
        border: none;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: brown;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .header>span {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .board {
        width: 698px;
        height: 598px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .spazio-gioco{
        margin: auto;
        width: 510px;
        height: 510px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        padding-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 100pt;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
    }
    
    .n1{
        
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n2 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n3 {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n4 {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n5 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n6 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n7{
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n9 {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .inf{
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-top: none ;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header" id="header">
            <span id="title">Tris</span>
        </div>

        <div class="board">
            <div class="spazio-gioco">
                <div class="cella n1" id="cella1" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n2" id="cella2" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n3" id="cella3" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n4" id="cella4" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n5" id="cella5" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n6" id="cella6" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n7" id="cella7" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n8" id="cella8" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n9" id="cella9" data-cell></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inf">
            E' il turno di : <span id="turno">{}</span>
        </div>    
    </div>
    

    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In js i declare some constants and references to evry cell of the grid, then i set the start when page is loaded, then i add an eventlistener to all cell (the log is for debug use), and finally i create the function win, but it returns even false. The cell.innertext is correct but it seem that function can't read it, idk. I hope in your help

Comment: `cella1.innerText === cella2.innerText === cella3.innerText` won't do what you think; each expression needs to be complete, e.g., `a === b && b === c`.

Comment: yeah what dave said is correct. you can covert to `(cella1.innerText === cella2.innerText && cella2.innerText === cella3.innerText) || ... `

Comment: I change the if condition how dave said, but now it return true, even with only one cell filled..

Comment: Edit your (question) js code based on the changes that you made.

Comment: Edited the code

Comment: You are also not checking if the cella.innerText is not empty `""`!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of repetition, it would be much better to do something like:

```js
const turno = document.getElementById("turno");
const players = ["O", "X"];
const str = "Player who won: ";
let playerXTurn = true;
turno.innerText = players[+playerXTurn];

let cellas = document.getElementsByClassName("cella");
for (let cel of cellas) {
    cel.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cel.innerText = players[+playerXTurn];
        cel.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        console.log(cel.innerText);
        playerXTurn = !playerXTurn;
        turno.innerText = players[+playerXTurn];

        win();
    })
}

function win() {
    if (
        wonIndexes(0, 1, 2) ||
        wonIndexes(3, 4, 5) ||
        wonIndexes(6, 7, 8) ||
        wonIndexes(0, 3, 6) ||
        wonIndexes(1, 4, 7) ||
        wonIndexes(2, 5, 8) ||
        wonIndexes(0, 4, 8) ||
        wonIndexes(2, 4, 6)
    )
        console.log(true);
    else
        console.log(false);
}

function wonIndexes(a, b, c) {
    return cellas[a].innerText !== "" &&
        cellas[a].innerText === cellas[b].innerText &&
        cellas[b].innerText === cellas[c].innerText
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap');
    
    html, body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 700px;
        height: 900px;
        border: none;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: brown;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .header>span {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .board {
        width: 698px;
        height: 598px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .spazio-gioco{
        margin: auto;
        width: 510px;
        height: 510px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        padding-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 100pt;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
    }
    
    .n1{
        
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n2 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n3 {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n4 {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n5 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n6 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n7{
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .n9 {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .inf{
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-top: none ;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header" id="header">
            <span id="title">Tris</span>
        </div>

        <div class="board">
            <div class="spazio-gioco">
                <div class="cella n1" id="cella1" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n2" id="cella2" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n3" id="cella3" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n4" id="cella4" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n5" id="cella5" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n6" id="cella6" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n7" id="cella7" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n8" id="cella8" data-cell></div>
                <div class="cella n9" id="cella9" data-cell></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inf">
            E' il turno di : <span id="turno">{}</span>
        </div>    
    </div>
    

    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice ! +1 from me. If you like, even the 9 'div's within `'spazio-gioco'` class can be added from within the js (rather than on the html) using a loop.

Comment: You're right, I didn't actually paid much attention to the html. But for sure the `cellas` could be populated using something like `document.querySelectorAll('.cella')`, I'll update that!

Comment: Hi, thank for the help. I fixed the problem checking the function returns true only if the others  cells were filled, and now it works very well! I know that is necessary some refactoring but it’s important that it work primarly, then i can refactor. Thanks to everyone Who helped me!